# I can't connect a webpage on my ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am building simple webpage.

I could run on my local host.

I made ec2 instance, I opened ports 22, 8000.[image]

I could connect with ssh and run server for webpage,

but I get this error
[image: amazon ec2 error page]

this is my github address that contain the code.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/MoreNiceJay/django2)https://github.com/MoreNiceJay/django2

Answer (score 1):

In your security group rules, open port 80
This is the standard port for http traffic

Other things to check: login to the host with ssh and use `netstat |grep LISTEN` to see if there is a process listening on port 80